# Geany find and replace characters with accent

Tags: regex, geany

I use [Geany](https://www.geany.org/) editor for some time, and find it very useful.
However, I cannot manage to find an efficient way to replace all characters which have accents **in a single action**:

`Rubén, Éliot y el niño`  `=>` `Ruben, Eliot y el nino`

In the **Search -> Replace** pop-up there is an option to use regex:

[image]

I wonder whether there is one regex (or any other efficient way) that would do the work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the regular expressions.

1. Go in the document to Rubén.
2. Select the é
3. Copy the é
4. Goto **Search for** and paste the é
5. Enter your Replacement-character

Comment: It is not what I am looking for.
I would like to replace ALL characters with accents (in the example - é, É and ñ) in one action.